# How to add data to images in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning

I would like to add additional data, such as financial and location data to my deep learning images.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I go about doing this, please? I’ve been using the fast ai API to train my models.

Much appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing you don't want to add the data to your images, but as input to your model, right?

Comment: That’s right, yes 

Comment: In this case you have to use a multi head model. its a bit tricky and really too long to describe, but in general... you take a model, you remove its softmax layer so you get the features. you concat the features layer with the rest of the data and feed this to a simple perceptron (several fully connected dense layers), then softmax or whatever you need to do to get the final results (i don't know if its regression, classification or multiclass). feel free to ask anything but unfortunately detailed answer will be very long.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with images, I assume you are using CNN-like model, in that case you could transforming the additional data and reshape it then add it as new channel of  input image:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, additional_data_dim, image_shape):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc0 = nn.Linear(in_features=additional_data_dim, out_features=image_shape[1] * image_shape[2])
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=image_shape[0] + 1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=5)
        # Add other layer below

    def forward(self, image, add_data):
        x = torch.reshape(self.fc0(add_data), (image.shape[0], 1, image.shape[2], image.shape[3]))
        x = torch.cat((image, x), 1)
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        return torch.mean(x)

random_img = torch.FloatTensor(np.random.rand(1, 3, 256, 256)) # (batch_size, channel, H, W)
random_add_data = torch.FloatTensor(np.random.rand(1, 10))
my_net = Net(additional_data_dim=10, image_shape=(3, 256, 256))

y = my_net(random_img, random_add_data)
print(y)
```